# How much gas does the overflow check cost?

Tags: solidity, gas

From solidity 0.8.x the compiler automatically checks for overflows and underflows. This costs additional gas.

My question is how much gas it costs and how much you can save by using the `unchecked {}`.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested the following smart contract with an optimization of: 200000

```
contract TestGasCostUnchecked {    
    uint256 a;
    function add() external{
        unchecked {
            a = a + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

executing the function add in remix result in a gas cost of: **43289**

```
contract TestGasCost {    
    uint256 a;
    function add() external{
        a = a + 1;
    }
}
```

executing the function add in remix result in a gas cost of: **43362**

as you can see the difference is the "unchecked" and this resulted in a difference of: **73** unit of gas

---

here you have another example:

```
contract TestGasCost {    
    function add(uint256 _value) external returns(uint256){
        return _value + 1;
    }
}
```

gas cost: **21531**

```
contract TestGasCostUnchecked {    
    function add(uint256 _value) external returns(uint256){
        unchecked {
            return _value + 1;
        }
    }     
}
```

gas cost: **21445**

For this example the difference in terms of gas is: **86**